# I have a touches began method but I don't want the sprite to jump again if touched twice?

Tags: ios, swift, touchesbegan

I have this touches began method which causes the sprite to jump. 
If I continue to tap the sprite it goes up continuously. I want to stop this but I also need to be able and hop over another object about 0.8 seconds later.

```
  override func touchesBegan(touches: NSSet, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
    /* Called when a touch begins */
    if moving.speed > 0  {
        for touch: AnyObject in touches {
            let location = touch.locationInNode(self)

            hurdie.physicsBody?.velocity = CGVectorMake(0, 0)
            hurdie.physicsBody?.applyImpulse(CGVectorMake(0, 30.0))


        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you use a bool to know whether the player should jump or not, and use an NSTimer to set this bool, like this:

```
var shouldJump = true;

override func touchesBegan(touches: NSSet, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
    /* Called when a touch begins */
    if moving.speed > 0  {
        for touch: AnyObject in touches {
            let location = touch.locationInNode(self)
            if (shouldJump){
                hurdie.physicsBody?.velocity = CGVectorMake(0, 0)
                hurdie.physicsBody?.applyImpulse(CGVectorMake(0, 30.0))
                shouldJump = false;
                var timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0.8, target: self, selector: Selector("updateState"), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
            }

        }
func updateState() {
     shouldJump = true;
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

When you first detect a touch set a flag which means touches are disabled from jumping and start a timer. When the timer fires you can reset the flag. In your touches began method check the flag before allowing a new jump.

Note that if the game has a pause then you need to consider how the timer interacts with it.

Answer (score 0):

Use a variable to discard touches:

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: NSSet, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
/* Called when a touch begins */
    if touchEnabled {
        if moving.speed > 0  {
            for touch: AnyObject in touches {
                let location = touch.locationInNode(self)

                hurdie.physicsBody?.velocity = CGVectorMake(0, 0)
                hurdie.physicsBody?.applyImpulse(CGVectorMake(0, 30.0))
                touchEnabled = false
        }
    }
}
```

And set to true in your `update`function, you could check if your sprite is resting:

```
if hurdie.physicsBody?.resting {
    touchEnabled = true
}
```